# Loading .gltf models in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am teaching myself three.js and have a simple script that should load an external 3d model.  There are no console errors, in fact using a code snippet I found it says that the model is 100% loaded.  However, it is not visible in the browser.  I'd really appreciate it if someone could take a look and let me know what I'm missing to get this to work.  I'm not sure why it isn't working at this point.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>External Asset</title>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="canvas.css">
</head> 
<body>
    <script src="../three.js-master/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../three.js-master/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="../three.js-master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script> -->
    <script>
        var camera, scene, renderer;
        //var controls;
        var loader;

        init();

        function init() {
            //Renderer
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {antialias: true} );
            var width = window.innerWidth;
            var height = window.innerHeight;
            renderer.setSize( width, height );
            renderer.setClearColor ( new THREE.Color( "rgb( 198,215,244 )" ), .5 );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            //Light Source
            var light = new THREE.PointLight( new THREE.Color( "rgb( 232,227,92 )" ), 3, 100 );
            light.position.set( 5,5,0 );
            scene.add( light );

            //Create Camera
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera (45, width/height, 1, 1000);
            camera.position.set( 5,5,5 );
            camera.lookAt( 0, 0, 0 );

            //Load asset
            loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
            loader.load( '../models/gltf/scifi-girl/scene.gltf',  
                function( gltf ) {
                    scene.add( gltf.scene );
                }, 
                function ( xhr ) {
                    console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );
                },
                function ( error ) {
                    console.log( 'An Error Occurred' );
                }
            );

            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: The model loading is asynchronous and you only call the render function once. So I would say that your model is loading after the call to render, and your scene never updates. Look at adding a simple animation loop, should fix the problem. Take a look at the animate() function in here, and integrate with your code - https://codepen.io/Staak/pen/wNvZVP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a render loop to your code. Right now you're rendering once, and your .gltf file is loading *after* that, since it's asynchronous.

From the [Creating a scene docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Creating-a-scene):

```
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
animate();
```

This way, the first time you call `animate()` will trigger the loop, and your scene will render at 60 frames per second. When your .gltf is loaded, it'll get added to the scene, and automatically render in the next frame.

Comment: Brilliant.  this fixed the issue and the model is now visible in the screen! Thank you!  I knew it had to be something relatively minor I was overlooking. I was going to add the animate function with an orbital controller after I was able to load the model, looks like I should have just went ahead and done that first.